# Return data in a corresponding cell if lookup matches

Tags: excel, vlookup

I don't have any VBA experience, and I know I've done this once before with `VLOOKUP` at an old job, but I don't have access to those spreadsheets anymore.

In **Sheet 1**, **Column A** I have *Product Colors*

- Red
- Blue
- Green
- Purple

In **Sheet 2**, I paste a report that Quickbooks creates
**Column A** lists product colors (dynamic)

- Red
- Green
- Pink
- Purple

And **Column B** indicates a corresponding numerical value

I'd like to enter code into **Sheet 1**, **B1** that references **Sheet 1**, **A1** and searches **Sheet 2 (A:A)** for that data, and then prints the numerical found value in the adjacent **B** cell.

So if **Sheet 1**, **A3** says Green, the code in **B3** looks at **A3**, attempts to find the same string in **Sheet 2 (A:A)** (which it does find, in **Sheet 2 A2**) and then prints the value found in **Sheet 2 B2**.

Can anyone help? I've tried searching the forums, but can't seem to find this exact question.

Comment: You may wish to bookmark the following page for future reference. [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not impressed by you searching but please try something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2,0)
```

in Sheet1 B2 copied down to suit.

Comment: Thanks pnuts. Maybe I'm just not using the correct terminology with my search. I'd like this code to search the entirety of Column A, that's why I was using A:A, because the data in the pasted report in Sheet 2 is not always in the same order, or even the same data every time.